# Approximate solution of an equation

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

please how we can calculate an approximate solution of the following equation:
Find $u_f$ approximate solution of the following equation:
$$
c(u_0 -u_f)= \left(\dfrac{A}{B \ln(\dfrac{u_0}{u_f})+C} \ln(\dfrac{u_0}{u_f})+D\right) \times E \ln(\dfrac{u_0}{u_f}),
$$
where $c, u_0, A, B, C, D$ and $E$ are real constants

I'am lost
Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: We need some more information. Is $c$ some function or a number, are all the values real or vector valued. It would also be useful to tell us which methods you have already tried.

Comment: Alla parameters are real constant

Comment: And youre solving for $u_f$?

Comment: There is a formal solution to this equation. If you want to know about it, you should write  what you already tried and  explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Did you try $u_f = u_0$ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want a solution of the equation, you don't need to use any approximation. Taking $u_f = u_0$ clearly yields a solution.

Comment: There are explicit solution(s) for this equation

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, I saw your post. It's just that the phrasing in the OP does not necessarily refer to the set of solutions, but rather to "a solution". I'm just pointing out the obvious: you can trivially get one of the solutions.